# A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

```
    <TreeView Height="400" Width="400">
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={Binding Path=Data}, XPath=*, 
Converter={StaticResource stringToXmlDataProviderConverter},ConverterParameter=/root }" Header="header" />
    </TreeView>
```

- **What is wrong with ItemsSource="{Binding Source={Binding Path=Data}?**

  ```
  Data = "<root><parm1>1</parm1><parm2>2</parm2><parm3>3</parm3></root>"
  ```

I try to use [this](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/11/14/wpf-hierarchicaldatatemplates-and-master-detail-data-display.aspx) code sample.
The differ is that I want to Bind the ItemsSource to data in datacontext.
There is nothing wrong with the converter.

**EDIT:**

```
<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}" Header="Parameters" />
```

Fills TreeView with one element (the string). So datacontext is correct.

**EDIT:**
This code works better. Is there a generic way to read XML in ThreeView? I don't know the structure of XML. In all examples I have seen you have to declare sub nodes types.

```
<TreeViewItem DataContext="{Binding Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource stringToXmlDataProviderConverter}}" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Header="Parameters" />
```

Comment: What does `Data` look like? What's its data type? What are its properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binding's property Source can't be bound because it is not a Dependency Property. Are sure you don't want to do this? :

```
{Binding Path=Data, XPath=*, Converter={StaticResource stringToXmlDataProviderConverter},ConverterParameter=/root}
```

EDIT:

A checklist to check while debugging bindings:

1) Have you correctly set DataContext?

2) Is the property visible to the XAML code?

3) Is the property accessed (put a breakpoint into its getter). Does it return the value it is supposed to?

4) Is the property updated correctly? Either of following scenarios must apply:

- The property is DependecyProperty
- The property notifies about
  its change via INotofyPropertyChanged
- The property value us finalized
  before calling InitializeComponent()

Comment: When I use your code I don't get any exception, but I don't get any data in tree. stringToXmlDataProviderConverter doesn't run either.

Comment: Is your datacontext what you expect it to be?

Comment: {Binding Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource stringToXmlDataProviderConverter},ConverterParameter=/root} with XPath=* removed trigger the converter but there is no data.

Comment: And is its getter accessed? Does it return what it is supposed to?

Comment: It is weird, I can't see how the property getter gets called, but converter not. Are you sure about the converter?

Comment: When XPath=* is removed the converter is called!